# How do I print a 2d array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, jtextarea

My array is:

```
String[][] name = new String[15][2];
int rowNumber = 0;
```

My add button is:

```
name[rowNumber][0] = firstName.getText();
name[rowNumber][1] = lastName.getText();
```

I do not know what to put in my list button (lists the first name and last name) into my TextArea called `outPut`.

The Whole Code:

```
`
public class StudentGradesView extends FrameView {
 String[][] name = new String[15][2];
 double[][] testMark = new double[15][4];
 int rowNumber = 0;


    private void btnAddMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        name[rowNumber][0] = firstName.getText();
        name[rowNumber][1] = lastName.getText();
        rowNumber ++;
    }                                   

    private void btnListMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
      String outputStr = "";
for(int i=0; i < rowNumber; i++) {
    outputStr += name[rowNumber][0] + " " + name[rowNumber][1] + "\n";
}outPut.setText(outputStr);
    }                                                                               

}`
```

Comment: We'll need some more information than that to figure out what exactly you're trying to do. Could you please post your actual code, properly using the code tags? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I get what you want now.

First we take the inputs...

```
name[numberOfInputs][0] = firstName.getText();
name[numberOfInputs][1] = lastName.getText();
numberOfInputs += 1;
```

Now you want to output this to a textarea...

```
String outputStr = "";
for(int i=0; i < numberOfInputs; i++) {      
    outputStr += name[i][0] + " " + name[i][1] + "\n"; 
}
```

Then set your output textarea

```
outPut.setText(outputStr);
```

You are getting nulls because you are specifying a static array size but you (probably) are not filling up the array with test cases up to that amount. So you are printing elements of the array that are simply not populated.

Edit: for comments.

Comment: Not poor English, I wasn't sure how to ask my question :$

Comment: Perhaps you can give more of a description of what you are trying to do? Place more example code? etc.

Comment: User enters first name and last name. Then they hit the add button. Next they hit the list button which is to list the first and last name

Comment: This worked: `String st = "";`
`for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)`
    `st += name[i][0] + " " + name[i][1] + "\n";`
`outPut.setText(value);` @taylorcressy

Comment: When I use this, it prints out the first and last name and 14 null null things. How would I make it so you can add multiple names. ie: name1 name11, name2 name22, ....

Comment: it only prints null null

Comment: Ahh, woops sorry! I wrote that off the top of my head. The rowNumber index should be an "i" within the loop
I have updated my example

Answer (score 0):

```
String st = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    st += name[i][0] + " " + name[i][1] + "\n";
outPut.setText(value);
```

This loops over the array and creates a string containing all the full names, separated by a line break.

This then sets the text using `outPut.setText(value);`

Comment: When I use this, it prints out the first and last name and 14 null null things. How would I make it so you can add multiple names. ie: name1 name11, name2 name22, ....

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String[] s1d : s2d)
   for(String s : s1d)
     System.out.println(s);
```

A simple way using for() construct

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to print any array to any depth is to use [`Arrays.deepToString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Comment: it wont let me use that

Comment: To use Arrays class, import java.util.Arrays;

Comment: `String st = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    st += name[i][0] + " " + name[i][1] + "\n";
outPut.setText(value);` this worked but it can only hold one entry and has 14 null null's

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
.
.
.


String[][] a = { { "john" },
                    { "jones" }
                  };
   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a)); //whole string array

   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a[0])); //john
   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a[1])); //jones
```

Comment: The text from the fistName and the lastName is being put into the array

Comment: I have changed my example, so it contains strings. Can you be more specific about your question, so we could help you in a better way?

Comment: I have 2 textFields, one labelled firstName and one labelled lastName.     The text goes into my array `String[][] name = new String[15][2];` after pressing the add button.                                         When the user presses the list button, it lists the first and last name of every entry

Comment: You could make a ArrayList and add that String to it. After pressing the list button, you can iterate through the list and print all elements whereever you want. Like this:
List<String> people = new ArrayList<String>();
people.add(someName);